# How to write a join query in HQL

Tags: java, hql

I have 3 tables in DB.

I want to make join query like this:

```
from Installment i 
join Payment p on i.vcode=p.Installment_Vcode and p.vcode=:vcode
```

but when I run it this error happens:

```
unexpected token: on near line 1, column 47 [from information.Installment i join Payment p on i.vcode=p.Installment_Vcode]
```

Answer (score 2):

HQL doesn't have an `on` operator. Joins can only be done [on associations between entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins), and can have an optional `with` clause.

Comment: It does not work with "with" too. error is: Path expected for join!

Comment: Yes. As I said, and as the link I gave you explains, you can only join two entities **through an association** (OneToMany, ManyToOne, etc.) between these entities. HQL != SQL.

Comment: These two tables have a relation (one to many) as I wrote in query:i.vcode=p.Installment_Vcode.                                                        vcode is the PK

Comment: That's not what an association is. Read the documentation, for Christ sake. You would have an association if the `Installment` class had a field of type `Payment`, annotated with `OneToOne` or `OneToMany`, or a field of type `Collection<Payment>`, annotated with `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany`.